# Session undefined in Express when AngularJS as frontend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, express-session

I have written webservice using NodeJS and Express. Service is running on port 8090. Also I wrote frontend in AngularJS and running on port 8080.

Mongo has username and password stored of all users

When I login via HTML5/AngularJS frontend, the AngularJS app in turn calls the http post request of express. User is authenticated. And I set req.session.email = the email address of the user.

I even am able to return and check in console log of AngularJS that req.session.email was set correct in express

The problem is that I created an authentication function called "restrict" in Express to act as middleware function to give access to other get/post requests only if req.session.email is not undefined.

But even after session has been set, when this other get/post request of Express are calling by AngularJS app, this "restrict" function blocks the calls because it receives req.session.email as undefined

Both AngularJS and Express are on the same machine. But I don't think this is the problem.

Express Code Snippet

```
var url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:5555/contacts?maxPoolSize=2';
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs(url,['data']);
var dbauth = mongojs(url,['users']);
// var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');

var express = require('express');
var cookieparser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();



var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(cookieparser());
app.use(session({secret:'v3ryc0mpl!c@t3dk3y', resave: false, saveUninitialized: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var user_session;

app.all('*',function(req, res, next){

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();

});

function restrict(req,res,next){


try{

    if(req.session.email){

        next();

    }
    else{

        res.send('failed');
        res.end();
    }

}
catch(err){

    res.send('failed');
    res.end();

}

};



app.post('/login',function(req,res){

//removed DB function from here to make the code look simple

        req.session.email = req.body.email;
        req.session.password = req.body.password;

});


app.get('/loggedin',restrict,function(req,res){


res.send(true);

});
```

AngularJS Function that calls the Express function to check session status

```
var resolveFactory = function ($q, $http, $location,LoginDetails) {

var deferred = $q.defer();


$http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8090/loggedin")
    .success(function (response) {
        if(response == true){
            deferred.resolve(true);
        }
        else
        {
            deferred.reject();
            LoginDetails.setemail('');
            LoginDetails.setpassword('');
            $location.path("/");

        }
    })
    .error(function (err) {
        deferred.reject();
        $location.path("/");
     });

return deferred.promise;

};
```

Fundamentally the AngularJS Resolve Function that I created should be successful but it is not. It is failing. Am using live-server to run HTML/AngularJS on my laptop and nodemon to run Express app

Comment: Can you share your express-session code please?

Comment: Thomas, I have edited the post and added the Express code also. Now you can see it again.

Comment: Have you checked that there is a cookie on your domain? And if so, are you sending your cookie in your headers to your Node server?

Comment: Cookie on the domain means? I am testing the product on my local machine. Also one more thing. If I test the concept using two app.get( ) functions, one which sets session and other just as a test get function with restrict function, it works. And req.session.email has value

Comment: Local development is not an issue. Open Google Chrome > browse to your domain (with port 8080) > open Developer Tools > Resources > Cookies. Is there a cookie from your app? Next, make a call. Back to Google Chrome > Network > *find your call* > click on your call > Headers > Check if cookie is send inside the headers

Comment: Yes the cookie is getting generated. But I observed that there are 2 Express logins - one has Method: Options and other has Method: Post

Also both have different cookie value in header. Additionally, there is only Post method, so what is this Option method. Is it right?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lcmyhplqz0mxt6q/AngularJSProject.zip?dl=0

link to entire code

Comment: I cannot run the project. Some packages are missing and since there is no package.son, it is nearly impossible to get it started..

Comment: You will be surprised to know that when I use Postman plugin of Chrome and call login function of express and then call loggedin function of express, all is okay and session is maintained.

It is only when I am calling the resolve function of AngularJS, which in turn is calling the loggedin function of Express, the session is not working. 

This is strange

Comment: You just need to install express, cookieparser, express-session, body-parser. Any other you don't need. In program also just comment out all functions below app.get('/logout'..) function

Comment: And next? How can I simulate the error?

Comment: In the root folder run below command on prompt

live-server --port=8080 --ignore=./express/ --no-browser --entry-file=angular.html 


and go inside express folder and run

nodemon app.js

Then you can open chrome and type 1270.0.0.1/

This would open the login/password page of HTML/AngularJS

Answer (score 3):

Ok! So the reason is that AngularJS is running on a different port 8080

Express was running on port 8090. This means that if AngularJS calls an API of Express, the session of Express would be lost unless Express allows session to be passed on to AngularJS and AngularJS calls the API of Express with `{withCredentials: true}` parameter set. Below are the changes that I had to make to get the session maintained when AngularJS and ExpressJS were running on different ports

In AngularJS makes sure any API you call of Express, it should have
`{withCredentials: true}` like this

```
$http.get('http://expressdomainname:expressport/api',{withCredentials: true})
```

like wise in case you use $http.post
the parameter {withCredentials: true} is important

Now on the Express side

make sure you have app setting like this

```
app.all('*',function(req, res, next){

//Origin is the HTML/AngularJS domain from where the ExpressJS API would be called
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

//make sure you set this parameter and make it true so that AngularJS and Express are able to exchange session values between each other 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    next();

});
```

Please feel free to ask me question in case you have about this topic. I spent days to resolve this.

Comment: Hi Tahseen, I am also facing issue similar to which you have resolved. I am using node.js express and angular4. I updated the code as mentioned by you but with no success. My node.js express app is on port: 4000 and angular on port: 4200. Could you please check this for more info and advise me what I am doing wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513553/express-session-is-undefined

Comment: Hi ijs, if you see above, i already wrote the solution too, after I figured it out. And it worked

Comment: Thanks Tahseen for your reply. Yes I did saw your solution and updated my code accordingly. However, it still doesn't work. I have also updated the link above........Thanks

Comment: You have done the part on NodeJS side. What about the AngularJS side ? Have you done that also ? GetCredentials : True ?

Comment: Yes, I have. In the service.ts file, I have this is what I am passing: `return this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/depts/getDept', {withCredentials: true}).map(res => res.json());`